# Error - Configuration With name 'default' not found- React Native android importing projects for Android

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I have two react native projects Project A on which I am working on. I had previously created another project for setting the orientation (also react native having java code to expose the orientation methods to javascript). I included the orientation project using npm install  into Project A node modules. As per the documentation available added the following entries in settings.gradle of Proj A -- 
`include ':orientation',':app'`
`project(':orientation').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../node_modules/react-native-my-orientation/android/')`

And then added `compile project(':orientation')` in build.gradle available within the app folder. When the compiles i keep getting the error Configuration With name 'default' not found.
Has anyone faced such a problem in including an external project to a react-native android project.

Comment: I have run into this, but not specifically with Android builds. This occurred when I tried to use the "java" plugin (or "maven") alongside plugins that use the new Rule-based Gradle model (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/new_model.html). My solution was to use new versions of plugins like "jvm-component" and "java-lang".

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue. Sometimes when you install RN packages with `npm`, or more specifically uninstall them, code is leftover in the Android files. You can manually delete this packages in the `app/build.gradle` file also the `settings.gradle` file and that works for me.